# Is there a GUI tool for MYSQL with query builder feature?

Tags: mysql, user-interface, mysql-workbench, query-builder

I am using MySQL Workbench. I can't deny that it's a very good tool. Unfortunately it doesn't have a query builder feature. So I wonder if there is another one that has a query builder feature?

Comment: You can try SQLyog. I have been using it for a while and find stable and easy to use. It has a query builder feature.  
You can take it from http://www.webyog.com/en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a good look at Navicat. It's one of the best I've ever seen.

http://www.navicat.com/en/

[Link](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql)

[image: Navicat for MySQL]